# Accessing elements in a ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have been playing around with the projects on [learnstreet](http://www.learnstreet.com/cg/simple/project/piglatin-ruby) but I sort of noticed something intresting about the way that they access elements in an array and was hoping to get some clarification. 
To access the first element in an array, I know that I can do something like

```
a = [2,4,5,6,7]
a[0] 
output=> 2
```

However on the learnstreet site they access the first element by doing something like

```
a = [2,4,5,6,7]
a[0,1]
output => 2
```

My speculations might be that they are using an older version of ruby that requires that you that. Correct me if I am wrong, am just curious to why it was done that way.

Actually to verify this, I went a step further and tried it in [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) but I noticed that using their approach only returned the first element of the array.

[image]

My version of ruby is => ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

Comment: Instead of speculating, perhaps reading [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) for Array would have answered your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is just another way of grabbing the first index saying:

`a[0, 1]`

Start at the 0 index and grab a slice of length one.  This is useful for grabbing a "chunk" or "slice" of the array.  Typically, when only involving a certain item of the array, it is clearer to use the single index version.  Namely `a[0]`.

See [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) for more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The best of grabbing the n number of index values

a[0..1]

It will return 0 index to index 1
eg:- a = [2,4,5,6,7]

```
 a[0..1]

output => [2,4]
```

It will be neat and clean but it will return the value in array not in string.